# Only getting the validation error for Password field and not for username field with HTML.ValidateMessageFor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation

I am having trouble getting the error messages for both Username and Password. I m getting the validation error only for the password field not for both, and if I test it by removing the password field then I see the username field is required error. Not sure what is the problem. the following is the code for it.  have the required attribute on these fields in my model class.The view and controller code are given below.

[image]

```
<div class="xmp-form xmp-Contactus container MarginCustom">
<p class="greyfontmod">
    Both username and password are <b>case-sensitive.</b>
</p>
<div class="span4" style="margin: 0 auto;float:none">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Submit", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
    {        
        <div class="xmp-form-row">
            <label class="xmp-form-label">Username</label>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserID, new { @class = "xmp-textbox" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.UserID, " ", new { @class = "greyfontMedError" })
            <span class="xmp-validation" style="display:none;">**</span>
        </div>
        <div class="xmp-form-row">
            <label class="xmp-form-label">Password</label>
            @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "xmp-Login" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Password, "", new { @class = "greyfontMedError" })
            <span class="xmp-validation" style="display:none;">**</span>
        </div>
        <p class="greyfontmod">
            <b>Note: After 3 unsuccessful attempts your account will be blocked</b>
        </p>
        <div class="xmp-form-row" style="text-align:center;">
            <input type="submit" name="submitBtn" value="SUBMIT" />
        </div>
@Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    }
    <div class="xmp-form-row" style="text-align:center">           
            <p class="greyfontmod">
                @Html.ActionLink("Forgot Username/Password?", "ResetPassword", "Home", null, new { @class = "Link" })                    
            </p>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Controller

```
 /// <summary>
    /// Logins this instance.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>ActionResult</returns>
    public ActionResult Submit(CustomerModel customerModel)
    {
        sessionHelper = new SessionHelper();
        if (ModelState.IsValidField("Username") && (ModelState.IsValidField("Password")))
        {
            customerModel = sessionHelper.ValidateLogin(customerModel);
            if (customerModel.BorrowerSeqNo == -1)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("Error", "Invalid Username/Password");
                return View("Login", customerModel);
            }
            return View("AccountStatus", customerModel);
        }
        else
        {
            return View("Login", customerModel);
        }            
    }
```

Adding my customerModel class below.

```
public class CustomerModel
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the user identifier.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The user identifier.</value>       
    [Required]
    public string UserID { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the password.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The password.</value>        
    [Required]
    public string Password { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the ip address.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The ip address.</value>
```

Comment: Can you also share your CustomerModel  class? The UserID/UserName property may not have correct validation attribute set.

Comment: I have not tried but it appears the code should work. You can try to debug and check the value of expression "ModelState.IsValidField("Password")". If this is working as expected, then check out the DOM and see if the error is being rendered but not visible because of some style etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the answer. Its a very silly thing that I missed. The below line

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.UserID, " ", new { @class = "greyfontMedError" })
```

actually has an white space in the quotes, instead of representing null or empty.so my error message was being overwritten with that white space and I couldn't see it.

I know its a silly thing.